# Is there a fade transition effect on basic Javascript slider code?

Tags: javascript, slide, fade

This is the script in the head...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "landban1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "landban2.jpg"
</script>
```

And in the HTMLBody...

```
<p><img src="landban1.jpg" width="1400" height="300" name="slide" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
var step=1;
function slideit()
{
    document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
    if(step<2)
        step++;
    else
        step=1;
    setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
}

slideit();
</script>
```

Is there a way to transition the images using fade without using JQuery?

Comment: There is always way without jQuery, jQuery itself is wrote in pure javascript, its just a framework. [Try this](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider)

Comment: jQuery is a library built upon JavaScript. So, definitely there will be a way of doing it.